# Consulta union, group by e count na mesma query filtrando por intervalo de datas

Tags: sql-server

Não estou conseguindo avançar na criação de uma query que possa ter UNION, GROUP BY e COUNT baseado em um periodo de data na mesma consulta. Para eu atingir meu objetivo, necessito das seguintes ações na mesma consulta:

1º) filtrar, agrupar e contar todos os pedidos de clientes em um determinado período

2º) filtrar e agrupar os clientes que não enviaram pedidos no mesmo período

3º) identificar os clientes que enviaram pedido com um status = ATIVO

4º) Identificar os clientes que NÃO enviaram pedido com um status = INATIVO

5º) Na minha query abaixo ainda falta colocar na claúsula WHERE o filtro por intervalo de datas que passarei através de parâmetro.

Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda dos colegas para atingir esse objetivo.

```
        select "Cliente"."Nome" as Conveniado, "Municipios"."Nome" as Cidade,
       "Estado"."Nome" as Estado, 'ATIVO' as status
  from ((((dbo.Pedidos prt
  left join dbo.Cliente Cliente
       on (Cliente.Id = prt.ClienteId))
  left join dbo.Logradouro Logradouro
       on (Logradouro.Id = Cliente.Logradouro01Id))
  left join dbo.Municipios Municipios
       on (Municipios.Id = Logradouro.MunicipioId))
  left join dbo.Estado Estado
       on (Estado.Id = Municipios.EstadoId))
 where (prt.Inativo = 0)

UNION 

select Cliente.Nome as Conveniado, Municipios.Nome as Cidade,
       Estado.Nome as Estado, 'INATIVO' as status
  from ((((dbo.Pedidos prt
  left join dbo.Cliente Cliente
       on (Cliente.Id = prt.ClienteId))
  left join dbo.Logradouro Logradouro
       on (Logradouro.Id = Cliente.Logradouro01Id))
  left join dbo.Municipios Municipios
       on (Municipios.Id = Logradouro.MunicipioId))
  left join dbo.Estado Estado
       on (Estado.Id = Municipios.EstadoId))
 where ( )  // AQUI deverei implementar uma busca por intervalo de data, baseado no campo [prt.Cadastro], que deverá retornar os cliente que AINDA NÃO fizeram pedidos no intervalo de datas
```

Comment: Por favor, crie um exemplo no [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) Para podermos ajudar melhor!

Comment: Creio que se tu implementar o where deverá funciona, se quiser tu pode criar o SELECT INTO #Memory, e entao acessar o #Memory fazendo filtros após.

Comment: Pessoal, eu trabalho com asp.net mvc 4 e Linq. Me perdoem por não entender bem de consultas sql puro. Roger, voce poderia me dar um exemplo de como trabalhar com #Memory no meu caso?

Answer (score -1):

Cria a estrutura inicial como uma tabela..

```
select * from (
     select "Cliente"."Nome" as Conveniado, "Municipios"."Nome" as Cidade,
       "Estado"."Nome" as Estado, 'ATIVO' as status
  from ((((dbo.Pedidos prt
  left join dbo.Cliente Cliente
       on (Cliente.Id = prt.ClienteId))
  left join dbo.Logradouro Logradouro
       on (Logradouro.Id = Cliente.Logradouro01Id))
  left join dbo.Municipios Municipios
       on (Municipios.Id = Logradouro.MunicipioId))
  left join dbo.Estado Estado
       on (Estado.Id = Municipios.EstadoId))
 where (prt.Inativo = 0)
```

UNION

```
select Cliente.Nome as Conveniado, Municipios.Nome as Cidade,
       Estado.Nome as Estado, 'INATIVO' as status
  from ((((dbo.Pedidos prt
  left join dbo.Cliente Cliente
       on (Cliente.Id = prt.ClienteId))
  left join dbo.Logradouro Logradouro
       on (Logradouro.Id = Cliente.Logradouro01Id))
  left join dbo.Municipios Municipios
       on (Municipios.Id = Logradouro.MunicipioId))
  left join dbo.Estado Estado
       on (Estado.Id = Municipios.EstadoId))) as tb
where tb. -- aqui vc coloca seu filtro.
```

Comment: Obrigado, irei testar.

Forte abraço e fique na paz!